# Cutted Control After Compilation (SizeToContent property)

Tags: wpf, xaml

In edit mode, my textBlocks appear as I want. But when I run the code, the textBlock4 is cropped ! I would like to know why and how to correct this, thank you.

**XAML :**

```
<Window x:Class="CuttedControlAfterCompilation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CuttedControlAfterCompilation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Cutted Control After Compilation" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="73" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**Images :**

[textBlock4 with its full width in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVnmL.png)

[textBlock4 with its width trimmed after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6FSx.png)

Comment: where is it cropped it? both pictures look the same to me.

Comment: Look carefully at the new images I just reloaded. - @d.moncada

Comment: I need to see the rest of your XAML to be sure, but it might be that your `d:DesignWidth` is different from your `ActualWidth`. You can debug your code, put a breakpoint somewhere and check what your ActualWidth is

Comment: I have edited the XAML code so you can now see it in full, thank you. - @PouyaAbadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases I had trouble using the `SizeToContent` property. But after several manipulations, I understand and use it much better now.

- **Troubles**

> **Trouble with a `Grid`**

```
<Grid Margin="0,50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

[Image : The `SizeToContent` property narrows the dimensions of the `Grid`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGOJY.png)

> **Trouble with a `StackPanel`**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="75" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[Image : The `SizeToContent` property narrows the height of the `StackPanel`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkBxG.png)

- **Corrections**

> **For the Grid**

Possibility 1 : Specify the `Width` and `Height` of the `Grid` (Do not leave them in Auto.).

```
<Grid Width="519" Height="221" Margin="0,50">
```

Possibility 2 : Set the value of the row in Pixel, as well as the value of each column.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="221"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="148"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Possibility 3 : Specify the `Width` and `Height` of each `TextBlock` (Do not leave them in Auto.).

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" Height="221" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" Height="221" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" Height="221" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="75" Height="221" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Possibility 4 : Set the values of the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` to the `Width` and `Height` (which are in Auto in this case) of the `Grid`.

```
<Grid Margin="0,50" MinWidth="519" MinHeight="221">
```

> **For the StackPanel**

Possibility 1 : Specify the `Height` of the `StackPanel` (Do not leave it in Auto.).

```
<StackPanel Height="221" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50">
```

Possibility 2 : Specify the `Height` of each `TextBlock` (Do not leave it in Auto.).

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" Height="221" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" Height="221" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" Height="221" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="75" Height="221" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Possibility 3 : Set the value of the `MinHeight` to the `Height` (which is in Auto in this case) of the `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50" MinHeight="221">
```

- **Conclusion**

  It appears that the `SizeToContent` property ignores spaces that are not used in controls when the dimensions are floating (Star or Auto). This can be remedied by specifying the dimensions of the control that the `Window` contains or those of its children.

  So, to take the XAML code from the question, it may be corrected by setting the `Grid` `MinHeight` to 319 and setting the `SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"` property to the Window.

  ```
  <Window x:Class="CuttedControlAfterCompilation.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CuttedControlAfterCompilation"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="Cutted Control After Compilation" SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight">
      <Grid MinHeight="319">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50">
              <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
              <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
              <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
              <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="73" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
  </Window>
  ```

I thank @PouyaAbadi very much for his contribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `WindowStyle="None"` to your window you the textblock will no longer be cut. See [Window.WindowStyle Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx). I believe the reason is the window border is using some of the width

Alternatively set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and you will be set. See [Window.SizeToContent Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx)

So the code would be

```
<Window x:Class="CuttedControlAfterCompilation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CuttedControlAfterCompilation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Cutted Control After Compilation"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" Width="148" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" Width="73" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This property is interesting, but to me it reduces the height of the window so much that `textBlocks` are contracted... it's a shame. [image : the window become so small](http://i.imgur.com/22SFvjn.png)

Comment: @EenAmok Then just set it to `Width`

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I have done several tests with this property and I understand it better now. I'm going to explain my research in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard window issue. You rely on calculated width values, but they gat messed by *ThreeD* window border sizes. You can make a window wider as Pouya Abadi mentioned, that would be perfect for this case. But it is not a good solution IMHO.

WPF is all about **layout**. I'd use *DockPanel* to make contols take up all the space available, or Grid Columns (1*,1*,1*,.75*) sizes. I'm not sure what you are going to make out of this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Background="#FFDEE2E4" Text="1" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Background="#FFC7CCD0" Text="2" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Background="#FFAEB5B9" Text="3" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock4" Background="#FFB29AC5" Text="4" FontSize="112" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
```

I personally don't like standard window and I use a custom one ModernUI.WPF by First Floor Software + my window style, that cleans up that modern madness and gives me full control on how it looks.

Comment: I am very interested in this ModernUI.WPF. Could you please tell me a link where I could learn more ?

Comment: It's a Nuget package. Search it by name. Thre are few with such names, but you'll find the one by the author - First Floor Software.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just increase the width of the window?

```
<Window ... Title="Cutted Control After Compilation" Height="350" Width="533">
```

The other option would, as mentioned, be to set the `SizeToContent` property of the window to `WidthAndHeight` or just `Width`:

```
<Window ... SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

This should be a simple fix.

Comment: The second option suits me better, although not easy to handle.